# Array to JSON with Guava

Tags: java, json, guava

I need put array into JSON object with Google Guava.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
State[] states = getStates();
for(State currentState: states) {
    jsonObject.put(String.valueOf(currentState.getId()), currentState.getName());
}
```

I tried use Iterables.transform but this is no working.

```
Iterables.transform(states, new Function<State, JSONObject>() {
  @Override
  public JSONObject apply(State currentState) {
     return jsonObject.put(String.valueOf(currentState.getId()), currentState.getName());
  }
});
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Is the return value of `jsonObject.put` a `JSONObject` as required by the function? Also, what's wrong with the loop? `Iterables.transform` creates an `Iterable`, not a `Map` (or `JSONObject`), so its probably the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: State the error msgs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need it to be implemented this way? It's not what `Iterables.transform()` is designed for.

First, `Iterables.transform()` does not accept arrays as its first parameter. You must wrap your `states` into any `Iterable`. The easiest and the best way is `Arrays.asList(states)`. Second, the idea of the `Iterables.transform()` method is to create a transformed sequence using a mapping function, not just to iterate over. I wouldn't recommend the following, but you can make your `Function` to be parameterized as `<State, Void>` and return `null` to simulate plain for-each semantics. Third, you must iterate of the result of the `Iterables.transform` because this function is lazy and does nothing until you start the iteration with an eager `for` or something else eager. Fourth, as long as your newly created iterable is not copied to any collection (by semantics; i.e. copied to a `List<T>` instance), any re-iteration over that iterable will cause one more transformation each time you implicitly invoke `iterator.next()` for that iterable (i.e. from the for-each). Thus:

```
final JSONObject jsonObject = ...
// ...
final Iterable<Void> voids = Iterables.transform(Arrays.asList(states), new Function<State, Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void apply(State currentState) {
        jsonObject.put(String.valueOf(currentState.getId()), currentState.getName());
        return null;
    }
});
for ( final Void v : voids ) {
    // do nothing
}
```

It's really a bad and ugly idea. You really need an aggregation function that creates/supplies your JSON object, a sequence of `State` elements to be iterated, and a bi-function that accepts the accumulated JSON object and a single `state` object and return the updated JSON object. Something like in its generic form (your can create your own functions and decorators):

```
public static <T, R> R reduce(Supplier<R> init, Iterable<T> sequence, BiFunction<R, T, R> function) {
    R accumulator = init.get();
    for ( final T item : sequence ) {
        accumulator = function.apply(accumulator, item);
    }
    return accumulator;
}
```

Guava does not provide any aggregation functions infrastructure and higher-arity functions (see the [idea graveyard](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/IdeaGraveyard), [Aggregator Functions](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/546) in the issue tracker).

Comment: Nice explanation. Of course, just using the `for` loop as in the first part of the question is still ten times better than that `reduce` helper method...